# Get dynamic value of dynamic element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have some `<div>` like:

```
<div class="padding-top-10"></div>
<div class="padding-top-100"></div>
...
<div class="padding-top-[an_integer_number]"></div>
```

And **CSS** for all of them:

```
div[class^="padding-top"] { 
   /* My custom styles */
}
```

My question is how to get `[an_integer_number]` above and put it into `/* My custom styles */` depend on its value **only use CSS**:

```
div[class^="padding-top"] {
   padding-top: [the dynamic class number -> an_integer_number]px;
}
```

Comment: simple answer, you cant

Comment: :( So sad! I don't want to use jQuery in this case. Here is the [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vietanhyt/p47whr0r/)

Comment: you cannot access the DOM or ShadowDOM without javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS code redundancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254335/css-code-redundancy)

Comment: SASS and LESS are owesome. But I don't think I should use one of them in this case. For e.g: `$class-slug: padding-top- !default 
@for $i from 1 through 100
  .#{$class-slug}-#{$i}
    padding-top: $i + 0px` will render out 4 x 100 = 400 line in my CSS file. Event when I use both `@extend %padding-top` and `if` clause, it seem to be 'doing each one by hand' like @tom-f say.  @@