# Can I programmatically determine a property value for a series of CSS classes?

Tags: html, css

I need help understanding an easier way to write this.

I have classes that have a number between 1-100 at the end of it. So for example:

```
.select1 {
    padding: 1em;
}

.select2 {
    padding: 2em;
}

.select3 {
    padding: 3em;
}
```

etc.

I want to match the number with the amount I want to add, but have no idea how to go about it in CSS.
Instead of actually writing them out is there a more object oriented way of doing this in CSS?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in pure CSS. You're probably going to need to write some JavaScript.

Comment: I had heard about object oriented CSS so I wasn't sure and was just wondering. I'll try to come up with a way to do it in JS until then unless anyone has some slick advice.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Could you explain for what you need this? It looks a bit like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a CSS Pre-processor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), with variables.

For example, with SASS you could do a for loop:

```
$class-slug: select !default

@for $i from 1 through 100
  .#{$class-slug}-#{$i}
    padding: $i + 0em
```

Which would output what you're looking for.

It's not a pure CSS solution, but it beats doing each one by hand. Otherwise you could also do this with Javascript, but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with CSS. And you shouldn't do it this way. It's the same as inline styles:

```
<div style="padding: 1em"></div>
<div style="padding: 2em"></div>
<div style="padding: 3em"></div>
...
```

Bad way. You should separate your HTML layout and CSS.